# Using Post for retrieving a resource

Tags: javascript, rest, web-services, tomcat8

I have a resource to retrieve from endpoint. Passing filters to retrieve the resource is making URL to be long so I am having to pass filters in body . So I am using POST for retrieving a resource is it agains the REST standard ? Also shall I use status code 201 for POST or 200 for POST success is also fine ?Also in reponse body shall I pass message description or is there any standard for message description and error codes json.

Answer (score 0):

200 should be the successful response header. If you respond with a json you could/should use a key named `success` to indicate if the operation was successful or not. The actual response data stays usually under the `data` key. If the `success` is false there should be and error code under the `code` key and a error message under `msg` key.
I don't say these above are `STANDARD` but they are a often used convention.

```
{
  success: true.
  data:[1,2,3],
  total: 3
}


{
  success: false,
  code: 101,
  msg: "Division by zero.'
}
```